# How to pass a double pointer to a function without segmentation fault C language

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to pass a double pointer as an argument to a function and I can't see why the segmentation fault happen...

Here is the function:

```
void create_path_list(char *path_, char ***path) {
// Convert the path (string) into a list of directories
   char *token = NULL;
   int i = 0;

   *path = (char **) realloc(*path, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
   (*path)[i] = (char *) malloc(2);
   strcpy((*path)[0], "/");
   for(token = strtok(path_,"/"), i = 1; token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, "/"), ++i)
   { 
     *path = (char **) realloc(*path, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
     (*path)[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(token) + 1);
     strcpy((*path)[i], token);
   }
}
```

Here is the main:

```
int main(){
   char **path = NULL;
   create_path_list("/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt", &path);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(*path)[i] = (char *) malloc(2);` how big are pointers on your system?

Comment: @Gabriel: `(*path)[i])` is a pointer to `char` (`char*`) to which 2 bytes are allocated to store a `'/'` and a `'\0'` (`strcpy((*path)[0], "/");`) . In which way does any pointer's size matter here?

Comment: You should not be casting the result of `malloc` in C.

Comment: @alk I see. I just skimmed the code earlier and thought it was allocating space for a pointer in that line (my assumption was based on the cast of the malloc result).  Your explanation makes sense, although this style of coding is probably a bit error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sizeof(token)
```

Will give the size of token, which is a pointer. That will not allocate enough space to copy for the entire string

```
malloc(sizeof(token) + 1);
strcpy((*path)[i], token);
```

You should replace sizeof with a strlen

You are passing a string literal to you function and then try to change it with strtok(). You will have to pass a mutable string.

```
char str[] = "/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt" ;
create_path_list( str , &path);
```

Also I don't see how can you know how large is your allocated array if pointers. You will have to either return the size or NULL terminate the array.

Set the last element to null:

```
 *path = (char **) realloc(*path, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
 (*path)[i] = NULL ;
```

And print it outside the function

```
for( size_t i = 0 ; path[i] ; i++ )
{
    printf("%s" , path[i] ) ;
}
```

Comment: @TomásBatista This should cover everything.

Comment: Yeah! I have to pass a mutable string. 
Problem solved!! 
Thanks a lot :D