# Why does my program produce seg-fault when assigning memory to a double pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

Why does this program result in a segmentation fault? I'm trying to have an array of pointers that is dynamically allocated memory so that I can have an array of strings.

I've searched for similar issues like [How to pass a double pointer to a function without segmentation fault C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534129/how-to-pass-a-double-pointer-to-a-function-without-segmentation-fault-c-language#comment41695035_26534129)

Please explain why it it seg-faulting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mem_alloc(char* p, char** dp);

int entries = 0;
int mem_allocated = 0;

int main() {

    char* p = "ksdfahj93qhf9";
    char* p1 = "siodfnrieopq";
    char* p2 = "erf9ih94gri9g";

    char** dp = NULL;

    mem_alloc(p, dp);
    mem_alloc(p1, dp);
    mem_alloc(p2, dp);

    for(int i = 0; i < entries; i++) {

        printf("%s", dp[i]);
    }
}
void mem_alloc(char *p, char** dp) {
    if(entries == mem_allocated)
        if(mem_allocated == 0)
            mem_allocated = 3;
    void** temp = realloc(dp, mem_allocated * (sizeof(p)));
    if(!temp)
        perror("Memory allocation failed!");

    dp = (char**) temp;
    strcpy(dp[entries++], p);

}
```

Comment: I am seeing some mess with not dereferencing of what should be and dereferencing of what should be not...

Comment: At which line is it seg-faulting?

Comment: You can't update caller side `dp` inside function as argument(`char **dp`).  fix like [this](http://ideone.com/0Ft10C)

Comment: `void** temp = ...`  should be `void* temp = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `mem_alloc` function you modify the function parameter `dp`.  This modification is not visible outside of the function.  As a result, the `dp` in `main` never changes and is still set to NULL.

You need to pass the address of this variable to the function, then in the function you dereference that pointer to change it.

So you function becomes:

```
void mem_alloc(char *p, char ***dp) {
    if(entries == mem_allocated)
        if(mem_allocated == 0)
            mem_allocated = 3;
    char **temp = realloc(*dp, mem_allocated * (sizeof(p)));
    if(!temp)
        perror("Memory allocation failed!");

    *dp = temp;
    (*dp)[entries++] = strdup(p);   // space also needs to be allocated for the new string
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
mem_alloc(p, &dp);
```

Comment: Rather than adding extra star in the function, I would remove the star in the `main`...

Comment: `void** temp = ...`  should be `void* temp = ...`. This way the cast here: `*dp = (char**) temp;` can be dropped.

Comment: @alk Actually, it makes more sense to make it `char **`, since that's what it gets assigned to and removes the cast.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors.  First is the one mentioned by dbush.

Second, you are not allocating space for your string before you copy it.  You can use `strndup()` instead of `strcpy()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I ask, why do I need to allocate memory for the string if the `dp` variable already has memory allocated to it for a new pointer? Is it because `p` will be destroyed once `mem_alloc` goes out of scope? Sorry I'm new to C.

Comment: You are allocating memory for the array of pointers first.  You then need to allocate memory for each pointer in the array to hold the string you are copying.

Comment: I'm confused, because I'm used to just assigning a string literal to a char pointer. But now, I have to allocate memory to the pointer after allocating memory to the array of pointers?

Comment: Your string literal is allocated already.  So if you want to assign that memory to the allocated pointer, you can.  But you were trying to make a copy of the literal, which requires new memory to be allocated.